# Abbreviation for fixed price of product sold in shops

Tags: abbreviations

What is the abbreviation for the fixed price of the product being sold (resale) in consumer shops?

Comment: That would be the *price*. What are you trying to answer that someone else would understand?

Comment: @SrJoven: There is some 3-letter abbreviation which I forgot which they use to inform resellers for how much they can sell on the consumer market (fixed price).

Comment: There's SRP/MSRP but that's not necessarily the price on the shelf.

Comment: In a lot of markets such a fixed price is forbidden (because it prohibits free market and competition). Are you sure you are not thinking about the _Recommended Retail Price_ or _RRP_ which _is_ commonly used (and published) by manufacturers?

Comment: I think it's either RPM or RRP. They usually printing on the product boxes as a recommended fixed price.

Comment: @kenorb If I see RPM I'm thinking revolutions per minute.

Comment: @SrJoven: now you know: when you rev up your car engine, it becomes worth a lot more: that meter tells you the current market price of your car!

Comment: RPM: Resale price maintenance is the practice whereby a manufacturer and its distributors agree that the distributors will sell the manufacturer's product at certain prices (resale price maintenance), at or above a price floor (minimum resale price maintenance) or at or below a price ceiling (maximum resale price maintenance). If a reseller refuses to maintain prices, either openly or covertly (see grey market), the manufacturer may stop doing business with it.

Comment: Googling images for "RRP food" I think it shows the right results such as: "such as X% Off RRP!".

Comment: MRP, as Kris mentions is another option - I've seen it for instance in India, but as far as I understood, it is not a price decided by the manufacturer, but a legally defined maximum price to avoid abuse through market manipulation.

Comment: It used to be the case in Britain that manufacturers could compel retailers to sell above a specific minimum price. It was done to protect small shopkeepers against large supermarkets that were opening up. 'Retail Price Maintenance' was made unlawful in about 1962 after heavy lobbying from a small supermarket chain that adopted the slogan: 'pile'em high, sell 'em cheap'. The little supermarket was TESCO!

Comment: As I recall, some companies tried to weasel their way around the UK/EU ban on manufacturers enforcing a minimum price by calling it a ***Suggested** Retail Price (SRP)*. Usually these days in the UK they just refer to ***typical** price*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the United States, we use MSRP: manufacturer's suggested retail price.  This leads to sayings like:

> Buy now and get 10% off MSRP.
>
> Buy one at MSPR and get one 50% off.
>
> I always shop at Joe's store because he charges a few dollars less than MSRP.
>
> Buying a car at MSRP is a scam.  Always buy at invoice price.

http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/msrp

Answer (score 1):

MRP: Maximum Retail Price

Is that what the OP is looking for?

Comment: The recommended price abbreviation is not used the most common, rather than maximum?

Comment: @kenorb: depends where you are. In India, for instance, products have a legal (!) MRP and retailers are allowed to compete by selling it for less but they are not allowed to sell it for more.

Comment: It depends on local/ state laws. I don't think there's a uniform practice across the English speaking world.

Comment: @Kris: Thanks. Can you add RRP to the answers as well? Googling images "RRP food" it's showing a lot of products with RRP on it. So I think both abbreviations can be used?

Answer (score 0):

The suggested retail price of a product (**[list price](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_price)**) has the following abbreviations:

- RRP (recommended retail price),

  > In the United Kingdom the list price is referred to as a recommended retail price or RRP.

or:

- MSRP (manufacturer's suggested retail price).

  > In the United States the list price is referred to as the manufacturer's suggested retail price or MSRP.